# How to find the third party module that is refering to MSVCR80.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, runtime-error

I have Visual studio 2008 compiled project. This is a large server application. And this application is crashing with run-time error from  "MSVCR80.dll". I checked all the binaries that my application is referring through Depends, but none of them were referring/loading MSVCR80.dll. So this should be loaded by any of the third party modules that my server application is using. But the problem is that there is a zillion third party this server application is referring (like for DB access, reporting, network, etc).

Note: I have analyzed the crash dumps,the call stack that is crashing does have only Windows OS dlls methods in them, so had no luck with that approach as well.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try running [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) in profile mode.  It will list all the DLLs as they are loaded and you should be able to determine who loads it.

Alternatively, run the application via the debugger.  If you look at the modules window you can see the module load order.  Find MSVC80.dll and see who loaded it